# Java bit wise operator (zero fill shift) not filling with zeros

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I've been getting a weird problem with Java, and have tested on both a Windows and Mac system and have this problem come up consistently.

Take a look at this code

```
int a = -32; //11100000 as per two's complement
System.out.println(a >>> 2);
```

I expect this code to produce 56, which is 00111000 in its binary form. However, it produces the value 1073741816, 111111111111111111111111111000 in its binary form. I understand ints are 32-bits in java, but setting the type of byte also does the same thing.

However if I declare a binary literal like this

```
int b = 0b11100000;
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(b >>> 2);
```

The first statement produces the value 224 (expected -32), while the second statement produces the expected value of 56

Am I going insane?

Comment: It may be easier for you to debug using `Integer.toBinaryString()` or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bit pattern in `b` is not `11100000` like you say, but `11111111 11111111 11111111 11100000`

You're using an `int` which is 32 bits - not a byte - and using binary literals doesn't change that.

Even if you used `byte` rather than `int` it wouldn't fix your problem, because the Java bitshift operators first promote any type less than 32 bits to 32 bits.

So the resulting bit pattern is `00111111 11111111 11111111 11111000` after the shift.

If you want to mimic working with an 8-bit value, you need to bit-mask the 32-bit value to the lower 8 bits before applying the bitshift (you may as well use `>>` rather than `>>>` now)

```
System.out.println((b & 0xff) >>> 2);
```